# PagerJS page-href link to an page with params

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, navigation, single-page-application

I use PagerJS in combination with knockoutjs to enable simple paging/history url navigation.

PagerJS support params like #search?text=testtext&year=2013

I defined such a page like:

```
<div data-bind="page: {id: 'search', params: ['text', 'year']}">
</div
```

text and year are two observerables in the view model. It works, if I set the url to #search?text=testtext&year=2013 text is testtext and year is 2013 and the page search is shown.

But, now I want an simple link to this page with specific params.

```
<a data-bind="page-href: 'search'"></a>
```

This line make an link to #search (without params), but I want a link to the search page with specific params. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your solution works, but the link is very static. Its hard to manipulate it or to connect the params with observerables.

The pager.js framework extended its functionality in the last weeks and now it's able to make an link with params in an extended and structured page-href syntax.

See the example below or here in the [Demo](http://pagerjs.com/demo/#!/navigation/href_with_params).

```
<a class="btn" data-bind="page-href: {path: 'user', params: {first: 'Philip', last: 'Fry'}}">Send parameter to page</a>

<div data-bind="page: {id: 'user', params: ['first','last']}" class="well-small">
  <div>
    <span>First name:</span>
    <span data-bind="text: first"></span>
  </div>
<div>
  <span>Last name:</span>
  <span data-bind="text: last"></span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This should be probably what you was looking for:

`<a data-bind="page-href: 'search?text=foo'&year=2020"></a>`

I simply added fragments to the URI and it seems to work fine.

[Example at JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Klaster_1/3K78X/).